# How to delete a multiple tags under a parent tag from XML with specific id ="something specific"

Tags: java

I have an XML which looks like this...

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <BuildModel>
             <RestSchema>
                    <CustType Id="regular.type1">
                          <DataType>string</DataType>
                    </CustType>
                    <CustType Id="regular.type2">
                          <DataType>string</DataType>
                    </CustType>
                    <CustType Id="regular.Command-Nest.type1">
                          <DataType>string</DataType>
                    </CustType>
                    <CustType Id="regular.Command-Nest.type2">
                          <DataType>string</DataType>
                    </CustType>
                    <CustType Id="regular.type3">
                          <DataType>string</DataType>
                    </CustType>
                    <CustType Id="regular.Command-Nest.type4">
                          <DataType>string</DataType>
                    </CustType>
             </RestSchema>
      </BuildModel>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

I am trying to reach the "CustType" for which ID is LIKE "regular.Command-Nest.type1/2/3/4" and remove all of them.

I wrote a code in Java to read the following tag but I am not able to.

```
        Document document = getXmlAsDocument(pathToXml);

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//TrustFrameworkPolicy/BuildModel/RestSchema/*");
        
        Object result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

            System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        }
```

In the above code I am trying to print everything that is under RestSchema, but I am not able to read through it.

How can I do this in a better way, I have to remove all the node as said above.

===== UPDATE =====

The first tag  is bit longer...

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="{Settings:Tenant}" PolicyId="B2C_1A_User_MigrationClients" PublicPolicyUri="http://{Settings:Tenant}/B2C_1A_User_MigrationClients" DeploymentMode="{Settings:DeploymentMode}" UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights">
```

So if you replace the old tag with the new one the code does not work. Why is that?

I tried adding the full tag and its content and now the deletion is not happening.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029427/java-xml-remove-item

Comment: If you have an issue with namespaces in xpath, don't just create a new question. Do some **research**, because such a question has likely already been answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by replacing `/*` with `/CustType[starts-with(@Id, 'regular.Command-Nest.type')]` in your XPath expression, then changing the loop to remove the found nodes. Like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory domBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document document = domBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML)));
    
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
            .compile("/TrustFrameworkPolicy/BuildModel/RestSchema/CustType[starts-with(@Id, 'regular.Command-Nest.type')]")
            .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        nodes.item(i).getParentNode().removeChild(nodes.item(i));
    }
    
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
}
static final String XML =
        "<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n" + 
        "      <BuildModel>\r\n" + 
        "             <RestSchema>\r\n" + 
        "                    <CustType Id=\"regular.type1\">\r\n" + 
        "                          <DataType>string</DataType>\r\n" + 
        "                    </CustType>\r\n" + 
        "                    <CustType Id=\"regular.type2\">\r\n" + 
        "                          <DataType>string</DataType>\r\n" + 
        "                    </CustType>\r\n" + 
        "                    <CustType Id=\"regular.Command-Nest.type1\">\r\n" + 
        "                          <DataType>string</DataType>\r\n" + 
        "                    </CustType>\r\n" + 
        "                    <CustType Id=\"regular.Command-Nest.type2\">\r\n" + 
        "                          <DataType>string</DataType>\r\n" + 
        "                    </CustType>\r\n" + 
        "                    <CustType Id=\"regular.type3\">\r\n" + 
        "                          <DataType>string</DataType>\r\n" + 
        "                    </CustType>\r\n" + 
        "                    <CustType Id=\"regular.Command-Nest.type4\">\r\n" + 
        "                          <DataType>string</DataType>\r\n" + 
        "                    </CustType>\r\n" + 
        "             </RestSchema>\r\n" + 
        "      </BuildModel>\r\n" + 
        "</TrustFrameworkPolicy>";
```

*Output*

```xml
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <BuildModel>
             <RestSchema>
                    <CustType Id="regular.type1">
                          <DataType>string</DataType>
                    </CustType>
                    <CustType Id="regular.type2">
                          <DataType>string</DataType>
                    </CustType>
                    
                    
                    <CustType Id="regular.type3">
                          <DataType>string</DataType>
                    </CustType>
                    
             </RestSchema>
      </BuildModel>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: I want to know why we use Transformer?

Comment: @horizon To print the DOM document. XML -> DOM is done by using `DocumentBuilder` to parse the XML. DOM -> XML is done by using `Transformer` to generate the XML.

Comment: Okay understood, I am trying to generate a new XML updated file, can I use Transformer to get it printed in a new file using above (Source XML, Result output)?

Comment: StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
System.out.println(xmlString);

Comment: @horizon To save XML to a file, use `new StreamResult(new File(filename))`

Comment: I have one issue...I am updating the question can you please look at the "UPDATE SECTION" on question?

Comment: @horizon No, since you haven't update the question. Besides, if you have a new question, create a new question, don't expand the current question.

Comment: OKay I am creating  a new question....Will share the link

Comment: @horizon Don't share. I don't care about a duplicate question regarding namespaces in xpath.

Comment: okay, trying to figure out why its happening